# How to force soft-keyboard NOT to hide textview/counter under edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

The problem is that **android keyboard is hiding textview under edittext (not edittext itself!)** while being opened.

This is my layout example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/big_image"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/comment_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/big_image">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/comment_edittext_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="your comment"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:maxLength="250"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/comment_input_layout"
                android:text="0/250"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Images below to make it clear:

[screen without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCDyx.png)

[actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ard.png)

[expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eKVJ.png)

I found several similar questions on stackoverflow, none of them has solutions:(
Please, help me to deal with this problem!
Be sure, that I used all advices considering `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
or `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
or `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
or adding this textview on separate from edittext layout, having framelayout as root,

but the problem is a little more complicated.

Another important things are, that this **text below edittext should**

- remain above keyboard while text is going on another line
- dissapear while edittext is scrolling up (as it is the part of edittext).

Comment: Check answer you can archive what you want with little different way hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I have already [log a ticket](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1314) to Material regarding this. 
The "hack" I applied, thanks to my awesome colleague's advice is this:
Whenever the layout is rendered and I click on the field which has the counter (which is the last field on my layout), scroll it to the bottom programatically, so that the keyboard not longer hides the counter.

Here are the difference pieces of code of my program which you can refer to:

```
    override fun onFocusChange(p0: View?, isOnFocus: Boolean) {
    if (isOnFocus.not() && getDescription().isEmpty()) {
        tnDescriptionLayout.error = resources.getString(R.string.description_error_message)
        tnDescriptionLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
    } else {
        tnDescriptionLayout.isErrorEnabled = false

        llayout.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                var v =
                    tnDescriptionLayout.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.textinput_counter)
                nestedScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0,v.height)
            }

        }, CoreConstants.MINIMUM_VIEW_LOAD_DURATION)
    }
    tvDescription.setText(getDescription())



    lateinit var nestedScrollView: NestedScrollView
    fun change(nestedScrollView: NestedScrollView){
      this.nestedScrollView=nestedScrollView
    }

    paymentOrderContent.change(nestedScrollView = parentView.nestedScrollViewParent)
```

I hope that this helps you!

Comment: You understood the problem, that is so great, thanks a lot for your answer! I got material beta01, but it is not working. although it seems like they had to fix it already... About your answer - if I write smth like `mCommentEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {...` and then your code for `run()` function in new runnable - hack is working just for the first time, have u face this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**You can archive your design using this design also**

In XML  use **TextInputLayout** instated of edittext

```
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/itFAuthAnswer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"// add this 
                    app:counterMaxLength="250" //add this
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTextInputHintLabelStyle">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/et_auth_f_que_hint"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This lines of code is solved your issue in different way and its also suitable to your currant design.

```
app:counterEnabled="true"// make it true
app:counterMaxLength="250"//set your limit
```

Happy Learning...

Comment: I am dublicating my comment from prevoiuos answer: The problem is not in counter. I just added this as an example - system works the same with counter or textview below. You can use this instead of textview in my code snippet. Problem is in keyboard, that hovers this textview (or counter in your example)

Comment: Where did the number **250** come from?

Answer (score 0):

please add this `app:counterEnabled="true`" `app:counterMaxLength="250"` to your `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:id="@+id/comment_input_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         app:counterEnabled="true"
         app:counterMaxLength="250"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/big_image">
   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/comment_edittext_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="your comment"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      android:maxLength="250"/>
```

**Edit :**

please try with this in your manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Comment: The problem is **not in counter**.

I just added this as an example - system works the same with counter or textview below.

You can use this instead of textview in my code snippet.

Problem is in **keyboard, that hovers this textview** (or **counter in your example**)

Comment: so why don't you use  textview counter above edittext ?

Comment: Because I need this textview (or counter in your code) to be below edittext

Comment: Please check again my question, I certainly has tried all this options (as you can read in question).
**adjustResize** is good while keyboard is hiding **edittext**, stateVisible is not necessary in this case. My problem is **counter/textview under edittext** (everything is okay in displaying edittext or counter or textview, problem is in keyboard **hiding just counter**, not edittext)

Comment: yes i read that in your question and i asked you to combine them , but anyway hope you will find a soluton

Comment: I have combined them - this is not helping :(

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking for one too.

Comment: @ismailalaoui What makes you say we need a `counterMaxLength`?